# I can't get json.loads to work - don't understand error message

Tags: python, json

New to development and python and trying to create a json file.

I'm trying to generate a list of people with a start time and onboarding time and incident time:

```
import datetime
import random
import math
import json
import numpy as np

# generate list of candidates

cand = input("Enter number of candidates: ")
cand = int(cand)
startRange = 0.06 # standard deviation (scale)
startTime = 9.30 #mean (loc)
onboardRange = 0.5
onboardTime = 4.5
incidenceRatio = [0,0,0,0,1] #1 in 5 chance an incident arises

def calCan(): # creates a dictionary of candidates with start times, onboarding, incident times.
    candattr = []
    candidates = {"candidates":candattr}
    a = 1
    while a <= cand:
        b = np.random.normal(loc=startTime, scale=startRange, size=(1, 1)) # startime
        c = np.random.normal(loc=onboardTime, scale=onboardRange, size=(1, 1)) # onboarding time
        d = random.choice(incidenceRatio) * np.random.normal(loc=onboardTime, scale=onboardRange, size=(1, 1)) # incident time - random.choice(incidenceRatio) - takes a random selection from incidenceRation list defined above.
        btime = datetime.time(int(b//1),int(math.ceil(100 * (59 * (b % 1))/100)), 0)#converts bnum into time
        ctime = datetime.time(0,int(c//1),int(math.ceil(100 * (59 * (c % 1))/100)))
        dtime = datetime.time(0,int(d//1) ,int(math.ceil(100 * (59 * (d % 1))/100)))
        candattr.append({
        "name": "candidate {}".format(a),
        "startTime": "{}".format(btime),#json doesn't recognize time so have to store as a string
        "onboardTime": "{}".format(ctime),
        "incidentTime": "{}".format(dtime)
        })
        a = a + 1
    return candidates
```

And then I'm trying to put this into a Json.

I can get the JSON to print just fine using

```
candidateList = calCan()

print(json.dumps(candidateList, indent=4))
```

it returns something like this:

```
{
    "candidates": [
        {
            "name": "candidate 1",
            "startTime": "09:17:00",
            "onboardTime": "00:03:37",
            "incidentTime": "00:04:04"
        },
        {
            "name": "candidate 2",
            "startTime": "09:16:00",
            "onboardTime": "00:04:19",
            "incidentTime": "00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "name": "candidate 3",
            "startTime": "09:15:00",
            "onboardTime": "00:04:13",
            "incidentTime": "00:03:25"
        }
    ]
}
```

but when i try to manipulate it using json.loads with

```
candidateList = calCan()
candidateList = str(candidateList)
data = json.loads((candidateList)
```

I get all sorts of horrible errors that I can't make heads nor tail of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "queue.py", line 56, in <module>
    data = json.loads(candidateList)
  File "C:\Users\Gordon Rose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Gordon Rose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Gordon Rose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

If I try and add double quotes to (candidateList):

```
data = json.loads("candidateList")
```

It still doesn't get me anywhere

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "queue.py", line 56, in <module>
    data = json.loads(("candidateList"))
  File "C:\Users\Gordon Rose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Gordon Rose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Gordon Rose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

---

Following some advice below - i have stopped converting candidateList into a string and am using json.load instead.

```
candidateList = calCan()
data = json.load(candidateList)
```

this returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "queue.py", line 56, in <module>
    data = json.load(candidateList)
  File "C:\Users\Gordon Rose\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: `("candidateList")` is a literal string, not a json. I don't see how that makes sense. Perhaps you mean `candidateList`?

Comment: @JohnColeman - if i remove the double quotes i get a different error set again:

Comment: You probably need `json.load()`. `json.loads()` is for loading `string` objects into JSON. Your `candidateList` is already JSON.

Comment: thanks guys - have updated the code. still not there yet unfortunately. I am -very- new to this so appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a properly formatted JSON, strings need to be double-quoted but in a string literal for a dictionary, string keys and values are given as single-quoted strings. This is the key difference between `json.dumps(candidateList)` and `str(candidateList)` (where `candidateList = calCan()`).

The first is

```
'{"candidates": [{"name": "candidate 1", "startTime": "09:18:00", "onboardTime": "00:04:10", "incidentTime": "00:00:00"}, {"name": "candidate 2", "startTime": "09:18:00", "onboardTime": "00:04:23", "incidentTime": "00:00:00"}, {"name": "candidate 3", "startTime": "09:19:00", "onboardTime": "00:05:08", "incidentTime": "00:00:00"}, {"name": "candidate 4", "startTime": "09:14:00", "onboardTime": "00:05:17", "incidentTime": "00:00:00"}, {"name": "candidate 5", "startTime": "09:12:00", "onboardTime": "00:04:38", "incidentTime": "00:00:00"}]}'
```

and the second is

```
"{'candidates': [{'name': 'candidate 1', 'startTime': '09:18:00', 'onboardTime': '00:04:10', 'incidentTime': '00:00:00'}, {'name': 'candidate 2', 'startTime': '09:18:00', 'onboardTime': '00:04:23', 'incidentTime': '00:00:00'}, {'name': 'candidate 3', 'startTime': '09:19:00', 'onboardTime': '00:05:08', 'incidentTime': '00:00:00'}, {'name': 'candidate 4', 'startTime': '09:14:00', 'onboardTime': '00:05:17', 'incidentTime': '00:00:00'}, {'name': 'candidate 5', 'startTime': '09:12:00', 'onboardTime': '00:04:38', 'incidentTime': '00:00:00'}]}"
```

both

```
data = json.loads(json.dumps(candidateList))
```

as well as

```
data = json.dumps(str(candidateList).replace("'",'"'))
```

work as expected.

Comment: data = json.loads(json.dumps(candidateList)) - works - no errors. Thanks John